# Proper validation is ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, validation

i have a field ProductID and another field ProductName.I would like a validation where if product ID is entered and product type is not selected it should alert user to select product Name (combo box) on the submit button click. 
What will be the appropriate way to do it? I do not wish to write any script hence cannot use custom validator.
how else can i write it?
i am using ASP.NET C#.

Thanks

Comment: So are you wanting the validation to occur on the server?

Comment: even if i write a c# function to check if they both have value, how can i show it on the screen with a small red flag that you get with validation controls ? i do not want to pop a message box.

Comment: on submit button click. pardon my asp.net skills.

Comment: Server validation is not required in your case. Just have a <span> in your html and populate it with the error message. I gave an example below, you can replace alert part with updating that span.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to do this very easily. Just wire a click event handler on your submit button. Take a look at this fiddle -

http://jsfiddle.net/8efopLff/1/

**JQuery code**

```
$("#btn").click(function(){

    if($("#field1").val() != "" && $("#field2").val() == "")
    {
        alert("Please select field 2");
    }

    return false;
});
```

Comment: i dont wish to do any client side scripting .

Comment: May I know any particular reason? Validations are best supposed to be handled at client side. You do not want your server to be flooded with such requests.

Comment: I can give you a server side solution, but it is really not a good practice to do that.

Comment: @Sam can you please elaborate? Server-side validation is always essential. Like you said, it's good to do it client-side as well.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev I think server side validations are necessary to maintain sanity of data (and must be done), but for basic form validations that OP needs, it can be handled pretty well on the client side.